# Error with Maven compiler

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-storage

I am currently trying out some sample code given by Google cloud and I am having trouble compiling it. Below is the sample code which I am currently trying out

```
package com.example;

import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.ObjectAccessControl;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Objects;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class upload extends HttpServlet {

/*protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Bucket = request.getParameter("Bucket"); // Retrieves <input type="text" name="description">
    Part filePart = request.getPart("File"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
    String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // ... (do your job here)
}*/

public static void uploadFile(String name, String contentType, File file, String bucketName)
      throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(
        contentType, new FileInputStream(file));
    // Setting the length improves upload performance
    contentStream.setLength(file.length());
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
        // Set the destination object name
        .setName(name)
        // Set the access control list to publicly read-only
        .setAcl(Arrays.asList(
            new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")));

    // Do the insert
    Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
        bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);

    insertRequest.execute();
  }

}
```

and the code that is giving me error is this

```
Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
```

the error message I receive is

> ```
>  [ERROR] /home/jy/Desktop/cloud2/example/src/main/java/com/example/upload.java:[50,21]
> ```
>
> error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project example: Compilation failure
>   /home/jy/Desktop/cloud2/example/src/main/java/com/example/upload.java:[50,21]
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
> ```
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure
>   /home/jy/Desktop/cloud2/example/src/main/java/com/example/upload.java:[66,21]
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>   at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
> ```
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>     ... 20 more [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Here is my pom file look like (very messy as I am just trying out the code):

```
<properties>
    <appengine.version></appengine.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev65-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
        <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
        <version>0.28</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <version>${app.version}</version>
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just 
                    localhost -->
                <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address> <port>8080</port -->
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remote 
                    debugger like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                <!-- jvmFlags> <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag> 
                    </jvmFlags -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <set_default>true</set_default>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is my Maven Version

> Apache Maven **3.3.9** (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5;
>   2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00) Maven home:
>   /home/jy/Desktop/apache-maven-3.3.9 Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre Default
>   locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version:
>   "4.2.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: Try removing <phase>compile</phase>

Comment: appengine version is 1.9.34

Comment: removing <phase>compile</phase> does not help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably copied and pasted code from an [official GAE sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples).

You should check the concerned full [project code on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/json-api). The [`StorageSample`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/json-api/src/main/java/StorageSample.java) and its [`uploadFile`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/json-api/src/main/java/StorageSample.java#L99) method provide similar code.

The concerned `StorageFactory` class is not found by the Maven compiler (and by any other compiler/IDE) because it is not part of GAE dependencies, it is a custom class provided as part of the sample project: [**`StorageFactory`**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/json-api/src/main/java/StorageFactory.java).

Hence, to make the code compile, you should copy it into your sample project.

---

Note: you may encounter further compilation errors, better would be to check out (or clone) the full sample project and have a local working copy to start with.